# Javascript slideshow cycles fine twice, then bugs out

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I followed a tutorial to create a simple javascript slideshow but I am having a strange bug... The first 2 cycles work perfectly, but once the counter resets the slideshow begins showing the previous slide quickly then trying to fade in the correct slide. Any idea what is causing this?

I have 3 images (named `Image1.png`, `Image2.png`, and `Image3.png`) in a folder for my simple slideshow and 3 divs set up like this:

```
    <div id="SlideshowFeature">
        <div id="counter">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="behind">
            <img src="SlideShow/image1.png" alt="IMAGE" />
        </div>
        <div class="infront">
            <img src="SlideShow/image1.png" alt="IMAGE" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

My javascript looks like this

```
var nextImage;
var imagesInShow;
var currentImage;
var currentSrc
var nextSrc

function changeImage() {
    imagesInShow = "3";
    currentImage = $("#counter").html();
    currentImage = parseInt(currentImage);


    if (currentImage == imagesInShow) {
        nextImage = 1;
    }
    else {
        nextImage = currentImage + 1;
    }

    currentSrc = $(".infront img").attr("src");
    nextSrc = "SlideShow/image" + nextImage + ".png";

    $(".behind img").attr("src", currentSrc);

    $(".infront").css("display", "none");

    $(".infront img").attr("src", nextSrc);

    $(".infront").fadeIn(1000);

    $("#counter").html(nextImage);

    setTimeout('changeImage()', 5000);


}

$(document).ready(function () {
    changeImage();
});
```

**EDIT:**

Also here is my CSS

```
#SlideshowFeature
{
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
width:800px;
background: #02183B;
height:300px;
float: left;
overflow:hidden;
display:inline;

}

#SlideshowFeature div
{
    width: 800px;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
}

#counter
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: is it normal that you have two `image1.png` in your HTML structure?

Comment: A more descriptive question title would be better. You can still edit it.

Comment: Script works fine for me. Please attach css here to see if it causes the issue and specify browser version.

Comment: @VadimGulyakin I added the CSS to my post. Also I am using Firefox as my browser. Its odd because it does the first 2 cycles perfectly and then every cycle thereafter it has a problem, it makes me think there is an issue with the resetting of the counter but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be in your HTML structure (and not in your JS):

```
...
<img src="SlideShow/image1.png" alt="IMAGE" />
...
<img src="SlideShow/image1.png" alt="IMAGE" />
...
```

I think you meant to put `image1.png` and then `image2.png`

Comment: That's not it. The first 2 cycles work fine so those img sources have already been changed by the javascript without an issue. I tested your suggestion regardless and still have the same issue. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

.infront must be in front and .behind must be behind

```
    .behind {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .infront {
        z-index: 255;
    }
```

And I also moved re-scheduling logic to fadeIn callback:

```
$(".infront").fadeIn(1000, function(){setTimeout('changeImage()', 2500)});

$("#counter").html(nextImage);

//setTimeout('changeImage()', 2500);
```

Looks good for me now.

Comment: Still doesnt work... on load the 1st image shows up... transitions to the 2nd image without a problem... then the 1st image flashes on the screen and the 3rd image begins fading in. Then that repeats for the rest of the cycles, of flashing the previous image quickly while the next one fades in.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry for incorrect answer. For me defect occurs only sometimes (once per 30-50 slides) in FF. In Chrome and IE 9 it isn't reproducible at all. That means that issue not in the code but rather it's a FF-specific visual defect.